# 'Failed to Load' error message when attempting to configure Cloud Volumes Services (CVS) on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, netapp

I had setup and configured NetApp Cloud Volumes Services (CVS) on GCP yesterday with no problem. However today, whenever I navigate to the Cloud Volumes Services (via search or burger menu) I get a 'Failed to load' error message.

I have attempted to create a new project but get the same error message. This also exists on a different subscription and computer.

Any ideas?

I was expecting the page where I can configure Storage Pools, Volumes etc